# How to add eclipse to windows 8 's apps search?

Tags: windows-8, eclipse

I want my eclipse to be visible in Search / Apps, so when I hit Win key and start typing 'eclipse' it shows up on the list.

How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the folder where you have Eclipse, right-click eclipse.exe and choose "Pin to Start".